# Tensorflow compatibility with Scikit Pipeline

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, openapi

I need to combine Scikit preprocessing pipeline from OpenAPI with Tensorflow as learning backend instead of Scikit learning backend.
Do Scikit Pipelearn supports using Tensorflow's backend?

Comment: No. It does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, we implement a custom scikit estimator which build the Keras model on the fit function. This way, we can build a Keras Model with custom dimension, depending on the pipeline.